# Store the value of `\c@page` with l3props

Tags: expl3, page, l3keys

I am trying to store the first page that an environment starts in in an `l3props` store.

I have tried

```
\let\current_page_int\c@page
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn {Nne}
\prop_new:N \g__environments_prop

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{foobar}{}{
    \prop_gput:Nne \g__environments_prop {foobar/startpage} \current_page_int
}{
}


\begin{foobar}
    ...
\end{foobar}
```

However, `foobar/startpage` continues to update every page after the environment starts instead of persistently storing the first page. I thought that `e` meant it would be expanded to the value of `\current_page_int` at that instant. What am I missing?

Comment: You probably need something like `\prop_gput:NnV` because you want to extract the **V**alue of the counter.  Right now you are just saving the counter itself.

Comment: Although, it is probably better to use `\thepage` because `\c@page` is the unformatted counter.

Comment: Another possibility is `\prop_gput:Nne ... { \int_use:N \current_page_int }`.

Comment: This will not be reliable due to asynchronous page breaking. You need a label.

Comment: You will anyway store an almost random number and it will change at each call of `foobar`. Almost random, because the actual page number is not known at the time the environment is encountered; another call of `foobar` will update the stored number. It's not really clear what your aim is.

Answer (score 1):

`\c@page` is a symbolic name for `\count0`; as such it's not expandable. So

```
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_jason_environments_prop {foobar/startpage} { \g_jason_current_page_int }
```

and

```
\prop_gput:Nne \g_jason_environments_prop {foobar/startpage} { \g_jason_current_page_int }
```

are completely equivalent. And they will store `\g_jason_current_page_int` in the property list, not its current value.

You might use

```
\prop_gput:Nne \g_jason_environments_prop {foobar/startpage} { \thepage }
```

but this will not necessarily store the actual page number, which is not known when `foobar` starts (unless you are sure that it starts at a new page, that is, it has `\clearpage` in the `\begin` part.

If you want the actual page number, you have to use an expandable method based on `\label` and `\ref`. Something like

```
\RequirePackage{refcount}

\int_new:N \g_jason_ref_int

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foobar} { }
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_jason_ref_int
  \label{foobar_ \int_to_roman:n { \g_jason_ref_int } _ref}
  \prop_gput:Nne \g__environments_prop {foobar/startpage}
   {
    \getpagerefnumber {foobar_ \int_to_roman:n { \g_jason_ref_int } _ref}
   }
 }
 {}
```

but this will be reliable only if the code is executed *after* some text pertaining to the environment has already been typeset, otherwise the page reference might point to the *previous* page anyway.

I used `refcount` because there currently is no `expl3` interface to the `\label`–`\ref` mechanism.

Another point to note is that each call of `foobar` will update the stored value, so it's not really clear what the aim is.

Comment: I'm trying to decorate the pages that an environment touches in `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{...}`. I had tried setting an `\in__env` macro when the environment starts and then unsetting it when it ends, but doing this, I always missed the last page, so my second thought was to store the page numbers and do a comparision between the first page and last page. Perhaps there s a better way...